# Category url goes to 404 page in magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento when i list categories in sidebar. when i click the category name means it will go to 404 error page. If you have any idea Please tell me as soon as possible..

and my code is

```
<?php
$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
   $categorycount = 0;
   foreach ($_categories as $_category):
         if($_category->getIsActive()):
         $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
         $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
         $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);


   ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo             

        $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><span class="categoriesHead"><?php   
        echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></span>
        </a>

        </li>
       <?php
      endif;

    endforeach;
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Try `$_category->getUrl()` instead of `$_category->getURL()`. Magento follows strict camel case notation for classes, method names, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in 1.5.1 and in my case it was the category url suffix which was expecting a .html suffix but the links were giving me blank. I changed `Admin>>System>>Configuration>>Catalog>>Search Engine Optimisations>>category suffix` from ".html" to "" (blank) and it's working fine now.

Comment: I encountered this same issue when upgrading from Magento 1.12.x EE to 1.13.x.  This fix works, but it makes me real nervous when I don't understand how it works or why it broke in the first place :/

Answer (score 2):

I spend so much time on this problem....  You might have made your categories root categories and not subcategories.  Simply drag and drop them into the default category and see if that gives you a better url.

You can see if you are getting a bad url by just appending index.php/*name of category in small case*/ to the base url

Comment: same in magento 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go in admin>>System>>Configuration>>Catalog and under Category permissions select No at Enable option.

Then click Save config and clear Magento cache.